# Update table with new rows using WHERE NOT EXISTS and LAG

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2016
I have an HR csv that I import every day into an Import table
I want to add only changes to certain columns to my HR table.
I've used the following INSERT INTO query but when a person acts up a position and then reverts to original Category and Grade later, the row with the original values does not appear.  Wondering if I can use a LAG in the WHERE NOT EXISTS section

```
INSERT INTO HRTable (HR_ImportDate,HR_EmpID,HR_Employee,HR_Category,HR_Grade)
SELECT IMP_ImportDate,IMP_EmpID,IMP_Employee,IMP_Category,IMP_Grade
FROM ImportTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM HRTable  
WHERE (HR_EmpID=IMP_EmpID) and (HR_Category=IMP_Category) and (HR_Grade=IMP_Grade))
```

Example of entries; the last one is not being returned as it has the same values as the first row.

This is the data coming from the csv integration:

```
Date  ID  Emp  Cat  Grade
20/3  401  John PT  P10
21/3  401  John FT  F10
22/4  401  John FT  F10
23/4  401  John PT  P10
24/4  401  John PT  P10
25/4  401  John PT  P10
26/4  401  John PT  P10
27/4  401  John PT  P10
```

These are the required rows to be added to HRTable

```
Date  ID  Emp  Cat  Grade
20/3  401  John PT  P10
21/3  401  John FT  F10
23/4  401  John PT  P10
```

Comment: best to start with providing data... you can use `sqlfiddle.com` or `rextester.com`

Comment: can single EMP act in two different category and grade in the same month?

Comment: Yes they could act in different category and grade within the same month.  The example shows a change across days, but typically someone may change up for 2 weeks performing in a higher role and then reverts back when their manager returns from leave.

Comment: you can also use top 1 where date<outer date order by date desc inside exists clause ?why didn't you try LAG and check yourself ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried the LAG but didn't work, can you confirm the context of the top 1 function within the exists clause?